# Geometry Nodes chart not showing up in the editor

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

As you can see in the image, the chart is not showing up. The area is all zoomed out, also tried to focus on the chart by pressing Z.
When I select it in the menu, it keeps not being selected and showing the button NEW.

Edit: added Blender file.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting the Z key to do? The Home key should centre any existing node tree in the node editor, assuming that's what you are trying to do. I think we'll need to see your Blend file, preferable with any objects that aren't using the node tree deleted to keep the size down. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: Thank you, I added the Blend file. I mapped Z to zoom to the selected objects.

Comment: We really can't guess when someone's remapped a key! :^) If you select an object which has a modifier on it in the Outliner, expand its entry there and then click on the GeometryNodes icon there, it appears in the Geometry Nodes window. It does seem to be a bit inconsistent though. Oops! - Just seen your own answer!

Answer (score 1):

To be able to edit *Geometry Nodes*, the corresponding *Modifier* has to be selected in the *Modifier List* of the Object.